# Does mongodb aggregation use sparse indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

Using mongo 3.2.

Tried to find information, does the mongodb aggregation us sparse indexes.

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

   > When placed at the beginning of a pipeline, $match operations use suitable indexes to scan only the matching documents in a collection.
2. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/

   > Even though the sort is by the indexed field, MongoDB will not select the sparse index to fulfill the query in order to return complete results: ...  To use the sparse index, explicitly specify the index with hint()

So, the question is, if I have sparse index, will mongo aggregation pipeline with match on indexed field us it, or not?

Comment: Hi, The aggregation framework has the option to add the `explain` option - if you already have a sample data & index just add the `explain` option like this: `db.orders.aggregate(
                     [
                       { $match: { status: "A" } },
                       { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
                       { $sort: { total: -1 } }
                     ],
                     {
                       explain: true
                     }
                   )`
It will let you know if it uses it.

Comment: @cohenjo explain in aggregation does not provide executionStats, that's why cant able to check that is aggregation using sparse index or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MongoDB aggregation will use suitable sparse indexes, except if the sparse index would return incomplete results for a certain query.

The excerpt 2 in the question is explaining an example of where a sparse index would return incomplete results for a certain query. In the case where a query **sorts** on a sparse field, but **does not filter on it**, that index cannot be used, as the results would be incomplete (documents missing that field would be incorrectly excluded).

Another case where the sparse index cannot be used is where you filter on the field but with a query like `{ x: { $exists: false } }` where the sparse index will not contain the matching results (because it specifically excludes them).

In your case as you say the `$match` is filtering on the field with a sparse index, the sparse index can be used **if** the index would contain complete results e.g. you are checking equality or using a comparison operator like `$gte` etc, but not an operator like `$ne` or `{ $exists: false }`.

You can confirm with the explain command, even without `executionStats`.

From a test aggregation query with `{$match:{a:4}}` and unindexed field `a`, a collection scan is performed:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
    "filter" : {
        "a" : {
            "$eq" : 4
        }
    },
    "direction" : "forward"
},
```

From a test aggregation query with `{$match:{b:4}}` with sparse-indexed field `b`, the sparse index is used:

```
"winningPlan" : {
  "stage" : "FETCH",
  "inputStage" : {
      "stage" : "IXSCAN",
      "keyPattern" : {
          "b" : 1
      },
      "indexName" : "b_1",
      "isMultiKey" : false,
      "isUnique" : false,
      "isSparse" : true,
      "isPartial" : false,
      "indexVersion" : 1,
      "direction" : "forward",
      "indexBounds" : {
          "b" : [
              "[4.0, 4.0]"
          ]
      }
  }
},
```

For a test aggregation query with `{$match:{b:{$exists:false}}` on sparse-indexed field `b` (this would return incomplete results with sparse index on `b`), a collection scan is performed:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
    "filter" : {
        "$not" : {
            "b" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        }
    },
    "direction" : "forward"
},
```